# IS partial derivative sqared is like the second partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

is $$(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})^2=\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial T ^2}$$ holds? thank you

Comment: Whoah, no way...  Unless you mean squaring as an operator.

Comment: would love elaboration/explanatio?  as $(\frac{d}{dx})^2=\frac{d^2}{d^2x}$

Comment: Try $P = T+c$ - what do you get?

Comment: @user114138 that is not what you have in your question though. You have a P in there, which as Randell says makes all the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That equality does not hold; their perceived similarity comes from notation alone. The $^2$ in the RHS refers to the fact that it's a *second* derivative.

$$(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})^2=\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\cdot\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}$$ and

$$\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial T ^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\bigg[\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\bigg]$$

Paul's example is a good one: Let $P = T + c$. Then

$$(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})^2=\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\cdot\frac{\partial P}{\partial T} = (1)(1) = 1$$ and

$$\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial T ^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\bigg[\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\bigg] = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\bigg[1\bigg] = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Counterexample: $P(T)=T$
$$
\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)^2=1\neq 0=\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial T^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

No. $\dfrac{\partial^2P}{\partial T^2}\;$ is denoted with the ewponent at a different place in the numerator and the denominator because it is a contraction for
$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial T}\biggl(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial T}\biggr)(P). $$

For functions of a single variable, equality  would mean that
$$f''=(f')^2, $$
which is clearly absurd: a polynomial of degree $n$ would have a second derivative of degree both $n-2$ and $2(n-1)$.

Comment: There is a family of functions that satisfy this equation, of course: $f(x)=a-\ln(b-x)$.  But this does not by any measure cover all functions.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For example,  let $P(T,V)=aT+bV$...  Then $\frac {\partial P} {\partial T}=A$, so $(\frac {\partial P} {\partial T})^2=a^2$, but $\frac {\partial ^2 P}{\partial T ^2}=0$...